# Why does drupal create revision table?

Tags: database

From database design perspective, Why does Drupal even create these tables? They are so much alike. There are modules & methods for getting rid of these tables, But why are they there?

```
MariaDB [park]> describe field_data_body;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| entity_type  | varchar(128)     | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| bundle       | varchar(128)     | NO   | MUL |         |       |
| deleted      | tinyint(4)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| entity_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| revision_id  | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |  ONLY DIFFERENT ONE
| language     | varchar(32)      | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| delta        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| body_value   | longtext         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| body_summary | longtext         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| body_format  | varchar(255)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [park]> describe field_revision_body;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| entity_type  | varchar(128)     | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| bundle       | varchar(128)     | NO   | MUL |         |       |
| deleted      | tinyint(4)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| entity_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| revision_id  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |  ONLY DIFFERENT ONE
| language     | varchar(32)      | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| delta        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| body_value   | longtext         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| body_summary | longtext         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| body_format  | varchar(255)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [park]>
```

Comment: This is an ongoing issue. Read [Duplicate data in field_data* and field_revision* tables](http://drupal.org/node/1279440) and add your voice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The revision table has been set up to track the revisions of a node.  Like Triskelion noted, there already is a thread up on D.O. Furthermore the reason the table is populated is for denormalization purposes, per [The aforementioned issue](https://drupal.org/node/1279440#comment-5122310).  Inevitably. this has some drawbacks.  The first of which is bloat.  Write speed is also affected, especially under a load.  The community has seemed to coalesce around using contrib to deal with this issue e.g. [Field SQL norevisions](https://drupal.org/project/field_sql_norevisions).  At some point it would be nice to have this in core, but a rock solid contrib module is the next best thing.